# Каталог: правильное ударение

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

На какую букву нужно поставить ударение в слове "**каталог**"?  Правильно "**катАлог**" или "**каталОг**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Только каталОг. Это слово не имеет вариантов ударения